# Why is the variable not available?

Tags: perl

In the below code block I get this error

```
Variable "$host" is not available at /comp/xx.pm line 404.
```

where line 404 is the last line in the code block.

**Question**

I am guessing that it is the `Capture` module that is messing up the `if (defined $host) { ...`, but how can I work around this?

```
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';

my $host = $::c{slaves}{$id} if (defined $id);

my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
    if (defined $host) {
        print "---delete $snap on host\n";
    } else {
        print "----delete $snap on master\n";
    }
}; # line 404
```

**Update**

If I comment line `capture` and its closing bracket, then it executes the expected `print` line.

Comment: I'm able to run the code without the error.

Comment: While certainly possible, i would always make sure to be very certain before suggesting external frameworks mess up. Especially those that have been around for a while. While your question is good otherwise and might very well be helpful for future readers, i would assume it is that suggestion that is responsible for the downvotes.

Comment: the code you show is all in a subroutine, correct?

Comment: I object to this question being closed as 'off-topic'. The indicated reason is too strict an interpretation of the rules. This question and the answers provided are very helpful to me, as I am facing a similar issue. The desired behavior is obvious: she wants the variable to be accessible (as is my case). The error is provided, as is short code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
my $host = $::c{slaves}{$id} if (defined $id);
```

Using `my $x = value if condition` is not currently supported in Perl.  It sort of works, but has weird corner cases.  This is one.

Split the assignment from the declaration of the variable:

```
my $host;
$host = $::c{slaves}{$id} if (defined $id);
```

You can read some more details in [the documentation for the related warning](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag#This-use-of-my()-in-false-conditional-is-no-longer-allowed).

Comment: `my $host = defined $id ? $::c{slaves}{$id} : undef;` would also work if you have a severe allergy to doing it on two lines.

Comment: This problem doesn't result in the not available warning.

Comment: @ysth, that's why I called it a related warning, not "the warning you should have seen".

Answer (score 5):

See [perldiag](http://p3rl.org/perldiag) for explanation:

> ```
> Variable "%s" is not available (W closure)
> ```
>
> During compilation, an inner named subroutine or eval is attempting to capture an outer lexical that is not
>   currently available.  This can happen for one of two reasons.  First, the outer lexical may be declared in an outer
>   anonymous subroutine that has not yet been created.  (Remember that named subs are created at compile time, while anonymous subs are
>   created at run-time.)  For example,
>
> ```
>            sub { my $a; sub f { $a } }
> ```
>
> At the time that f is created, it can't capture the current value of $a, since the anonymous subroutine hasn't been created
>              yet.  Conversely, the following won't give a warning since the anonymous subroutine has by now been created and is live:
>
> ```
>            sub { my $a; eval 'sub f { $a }' }->();
> ```
>
> The second situation is caused by an eval accessing a variable that has gone out of scope, for example,
>
> ```
>            sub f {
>                my $a;
>                sub { eval '$a' }
>            }
>            f()->();
> ```
>
> Here, when the '$a' in the eval is being compiled, f() is not currently being executed, so its $a is not available for capture.

Comment: Very interesting. How does that translate into my example? Is it indeed `capture` that messes things up?

Comment: @ialarmedalien I have now updated the OP, as the problem goes away if I comment the `capture` line.